# How to create a ROC curve plot with log scale for X axis?

Tags: plot, roc

I have a big database and I run a ROC curve with `nsROC` package. I need to have log scale on x-axis. How can I do it with plot function?

```
ns_roc <- gROC(sei$score, sei$label)

par(xlog = TRUE)
plot(ns_roc, xlim = range(1e-6:1), ylim = range(0:1), xaxs = "r", yaxs = "r")
```

This is my error message:

```
Error in plot.default(xx, c(0, obj$roc, 1), type = type, xlim = c(0, 1),  : 
  formal argument "xlim" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `plot` here is not the generic R `plot` function.  It is invoking `plot.groc` which is a separate function that defines `xlim` explicitly.

Type `plot.groc` after you install your package to see the whole function.  You will see this inside the function:

```
[removed]

plot(xx, c(0, obj$roc, 1), type = type, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 
1), lwd = lwd, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, main = main, 
...)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, 0.01), labels = F, tck = -0.01)
axis(1, at = seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1), labels = F, tck = -0.02)

[removed]
```

This is your problem.

You may have to make your own version of this function.

It is not clear to me whether you want logarithmic ticks on your x-axis (e.g., `axis(1, c(0,0.001,0.01,0.1,1))` instead of equally-spaced tickmarks) or if you want the whole x-axis on the log scale (e.g., log(False-Positive Rate) between -Inf and 0 at different powers of 10).

I'm not sure why using a logarithmic axis (-Inf to 0) is a good idea here, which is what you seem to want to graph. You may not be able to use the `nsROC` package without 1) modifying your ROC curve data at `x=0`, and 2) writing your own functions for a log-axis in an otherwise perfectly interpretable set of ROC curves. It makes interpreting the AUC more difficult as well.